# How to know if two picture boxes have collided on specific bounds. c#

Tags: c#, picturebox

I have two picture boxes: **pbX** and **pbY**.

I'd like to know when **pbX right bound** intersects with **pbY left bound**.

This is the code I have:

```
 if (this.pbX.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbY.Bounds))
            {
                /*Show message*/
            }
```

How could I do it so?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one more check, maybe like this:

```
if (pbX.Bounds.IntersectsWith(pbY.Bounds))
{
    if (pbX.Right >= pbY.Left) 
    {
       /*Show message*/
    }
}
```